# Is it possible to get explicit solution to the following equation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, equation-solving, equations

Note, the question is edited.

I set the restrictions as suggested and received the following outcome:

```
syms f1 f2 M b1 b2
assume (M > 1 & b1 > 0 & b2 > 0)
S = solve ( [(f1^M)/(f2^M) - M/(b1*f1) + M + 1 == 0, ...
(f2^M)/(f1^M) - M/(b2*f2) + M + 1 == 0], [f1,f2] )

Warning: The solutions are parameterized by the symbols: z, z1. To include parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 
> In solve>warnIfParams at 511
  In solve at 361 


 Warning: The solutions are valid under the following conditions: M + z^M/z1^M - M/(b1*z) + 1 == 0 & M + z1^M/z^M - M/(b2*z1) + 1 == 0 & z < 0 & z1 < 0. To include parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 


> In solve>warnIfParams at 518
  In solve at 361 

S = 

f1: [1x1 sym]
f2: [1x1 sym]
```

Even if I restrict values of **f1** and **f2** to be negative, I receive the same output as above.

With the above equations, I am trying to replicate Reaction Curves which appear in Hirshleifer J. (1995), "Anarchy and Its Breakdown." *J. of Political Economy* (in case you need more information)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are not getting an explicit, closed solution because there is none that holds for the general case of any real `M`, `b1` and `b2`.

In particular for the case `M = 0` both equations simplify to

```
  (...)^0 + 0 / (...) + 0 + 1   =   1 + 0 + 0 + 1   =   2    =    0
```

which clearly has no solution at all. How would you expect Matlab to handle this?

If you have some additional constraints on `M` or `b` you should try to add them.

Comment: since there was too much text, I posted my comment as an answer as you can see below

Comment: How is this the same output as before? `f1: [1x1 sym]` vs `f1: [0x1 sym]`, this looks like Matlab *does* return a solution. What is `f1`?

Answer (score -1):

@mbschenkel, I set the restrictions as suggested and received the following outcome:

```
syms f1 f2 M b1 b2
assume (M > 1 & b1 > 0 & b2 > 0)
S = solve ( [(f1^M)/(f2^M) - M/(b1*f1) + M + 1 == 0, ...
(f2^M)/(f1^M) - M/(b2*f2) + M + 1 == 0], [f1,f2] )

Warning: The solutions are parameterized by the symbols: z, z1. To include parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 
> In solve>warnIfParams at 511
  In solve at 361 


Warning: The solutions are valid under the following conditions: M + z^M/z1^M - M/(b1*z) + 1 == 0 & M + z1^M/z^M - M/(b2*z1) + 1 == 0 & z < 0 & z1 < 0. To include parameters and conditions in the solution, specify the 'ReturnConditions' option. 


> In solve>warnIfParams at 518
  In solve at 361 

S = 

f1: [1x1 sym]
f2: [1x1 sym]
```

Even if I restrict values of **f1** and **f2** to be negative, I receive the same output as above.

With the above equations, I am trying to replicate Reaction Curves  which appear in Hirshleifer J. (1995), "Anarchy and Its Breakdown." *J. of Political Economy* (in case you need more information)

Comment: Downvoted, because you should add this to your question and not post comments as answers (unless they actually answer it of course). You can write "Edit: ..." or something to distinguish the original question from later additions.